# SSRS and Interactive Sorting work in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have implemented a reporting engine in mvc using html rendering. I had to create custom paging functionality based on the metadata returned via the render method. I am now looking at implementing interactive sorting in the same fashion which is looking like a more daunting task. It seems there is a setting in the **HTML Device Information Settings** header for html rendering called **ActionScript**.

**ActionScript(*)-** 
*Specifies the name of the JavaScript function to use when an action event occurs, such as a drillthrough or bookmark click. If this parameter is specified, an action event will trigger the named JavaScript function instead of a postback to the server.*

My question is has anyone used this feature? Since I lose authentication after the report is rendered I will have to somehow make authenticated callbacks in the controller. It seems to me it may be easier just to add parameters for sorting in the report, however I would like to keep the interactive sorting in the report.

--Edit Solution1---

It turns out that the * next to script name above means the ActionScript parameter is being depreciated after ssrs 2012. Thus, I decided not to pursue it. If anyone else stumbles upon this then the best way I thought of to simulate interactive sorting without post backs is detailed below:

**On the Report**

```
1. Add a parameter to the report SortField1
2. Add a Sort condition to the Tablix or group you wish to sort. Tablix-Sort Expressions
3. Set the expression of the sort to Fields(Paremeters!SortField1.Value).Value
4. Set the default value of parameter SortField1 to the default sort field
5. Set Allow Nulls of the parameter to true.
6. Add a image or label for each column you would like to sort by
7. Create a action for the element created in step 7 with code similar to
  ="javascript:void(reportSortRequest('ColumsFieldName'))"
 NOTE: Your view or view descendant will have need to have an identical function defined to accept the action
```

**In the View**

1. Implement the function reportSortRequest(fieldName). This should set
   Model.SortField1 and invoke the post back to the controller to
   re-render the report.

**In the Controller (This is for Ajax post backs that sends a model that will have a field SortField1)**

1. Call the render with report information including SortField1.

**Updated with client script that works to access the report markup wrapper.**

The report element generated by the ssrs markup can be accessed in your view by its tags. I have that found the following will work using the predetermined ssrs wrapper element **#oReportCell**":

Loaded in iframe :

```
var frameContent = $("#myIFrame").contents();        
var ssrsContentElement = frameContent.find("#oReportCell");
```

Loaded in div:

```
var ssrsContentElement = $("#myDiv").find("#oReportCell");
```

Function to load html blob into either a frame or a div. Depending how the report was configured, the content is either a url of a temp file or the html markup.

```
function setReportContent(content, isUrl, renderInIFrame) {        
    if (isUrl) {
        if (renderInIFrame) {
            $("#reportContent").html("<iframe id='reportFrame' sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts' width='100%' height='300' scrolling='yes' onload='onReportFrameLoad();'\></iframe>");
            $('#reportFrame').attr('src', content);               
        }
        else 
            $("#reportContent").load(content);              

    }
    else {
        if (renderInIFrame) {
            $("#reportContent").html("<iframe id='reportFrame' sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts' width='100%' height='300' scrolling='yes' onload='onReportFrameLoad();'\></iframe>");               
            $('#reportFrame').contents().find('html').html(content);
        }
        else      
            $("#reportContent").html(content);            
    }
    if(!renderInIFrame)
        showReportWaitIndicator(false);
    $("#reportContent").show();
}
```

Notice that if you want report images with auto-resize property set to be rendered correctly you have to turn on `allow-scripts` so that the ssrs resize js functions can fire, be careful.

Comment: how I can add "javascript:void(reportSortRequest('ColumsFieldName'))" to table header ?

Comment: Through the SSRS.Label.Action.Url= Link

Comment: you may think of creating a more elaborate setup in which the header would send in a SortUp|SortDown|SortNone as I have no time :(

Comment: I can't pass current element in href tag do you have any alternate("javascript:void(reportSortRequest(this))")

Comment: What do you mean by current element?

Comment: anchor tag (by passing this keyword as a parameter to reportSortRequest(this) function )

Comment: I added how you could access the main html report div in the client. I don't know if this is what you are looking for but I hope it helps.